# Stop ordering and redirecting to a page from the Observer with an error message

Tags: magento-1.9

How I can stop ordering and redirecting to a page from the Observer with an error message.

```
    public function setSubscribeField($observer)
        {
            if(Mage::app()->getRequest()->isPost()){
                $postData = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost();
                $session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
                if(isset($postData['mailchimp_subscription'])){
                    $session->setData('mailchimp_subscription',$postData['mailchimp_subscription']);
                }else {
                    if($postData['mailchimp_subscription'] != 'on' && Mage::helper('subscription')->isRequired()){
   ????????
                    }
                }
            }

            return $this;
        }
```

If this parameter is required, than I must redirect to page with `form` and show error message .
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirection in observer doesn’t work normally as it do in Blocks, templates and controllers. Also there is no standard code to redirect from observer that works in every situation.

You will need an argument to achieve redirect when using below code:

```
public function observingMethod(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $observer->getRequest()->setParam('return_url',$urlToRedirect);
}
```

Note that $observer object should have getRequest() method to make above code work. You may need to use $observer->getEvent()->getFront()->getRequest() otherwise, or simply var_dump/Mage::log $observer to get better idea what methods the object have.

Or you can use below code which is not recommended:

```
public function observingMethod() {
    header('Location: ' . $urlToRedirect);
    exit;
}
```

We don’t need any arguments using above method.

Another approach, again not recommended:

```
public function observingMethod(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{    
    $response = $observer->getResponse();
    //$response = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse();
    $response->setRedirect($urlToRedirect);

    Mage::app()->getFrontController()->sendResponse();
}
```

Link: https://web.archive.org/web/20211204202657/http://ka.lpe.sh/2013/07/21/magento-redirect-from-observer/

Comment: Which event do you use?

Comment: @sv3n custom event

Answer (score 1):

I am only 90% sure that the redirect will work because I have only used it in controllers (not observers), but if it does, the error message should display at the top of the page like any other native Magento errors.

```
public function setSubscribeField($observer)
    {
        if(Mage::app()->getRequest()->isPost()){
            $postData = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost();
            $session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
            if(isset($postData['mailchimp_subscription'])){
                $session->setData('mailchimp_subscription',$postData['mailchimp_subscription']);
            }else {
                if($postData['mailchimp_subscription'] != 'on' && Mage::helper('subscription')->isRequired()){

// add your error to the session
                    $session->addError('[YOUR ERROR MESSAGE]');
// redirect to the page that the user came from 
                    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                }
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

**Note:**

The session that you have already pulled with `$session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');` is not the only type of session that can be used in this scenario.  So, if the redirect works and the error does not, try

`Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError('[YOUR ERROR MESSAGE]');`

or

`Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('[YOUR ERROR MESSAGE]');`

[For more on session-types take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9803979/whats-the-difference-between-the-different-magento-session-types)

Comment: `There has been an error processing your request` if I use `$this->_redirect('*/*/');`(